# How to reset the BIOS without opening the notebook?

Tags: laptop, bios, power, reset, dell-vostro

I have a vostro 5470, I installed the hackintosh, but when I turned it off it does not turn on anymore (the leds do not turn on), I did some research and found that the way mac os shut down the machine causes this problem, to correct the problem I have to reset the bios and for this I need to open the machine, to remove the battery.

But I want to do more testing trying to install hackintosh, I was wondering if it is possible to reset the bios without having to open the computer, whether to a shortcut on the keyboard or something.

I have experience with hardware, and only heard rumors about resetting the bios without having to open the machine, but in this case I would have to open the machine several times, since one hour or another I would turn off the machine until I figured out how to solve it.

Comment: Try holding the power button for 30+ seconds.

Comment: I tested but it did not work

Answer (score 1):

Add a normally-closed SPST switch in series with the battery, using thin, perhaps enameled, wire. Snake the leads outside the case. For a neater installation, put the switch on the case or put it in a small bottle.

For a coin cell, you can make a temporary adapter without soldering to the circuit board: put a bit of copper foil on each side of some thin plastic and run the switch leads to the foil. Put the adapter between the negative side of the cell (button contact) and the cell holder.

**Caution:** beware of shorting to another component and of electrostatic discharge (ESD)!